# Why do Apache Airflow scheduled DAGs prioritize over manually triggered DAGs?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that runs on a schedule, and the tasks inside it find a file in a path, process it, and move that file to an archive folder.

Instead of waiting for the schedule, I manually triggered the DAG.  The manually triggered DAG executed it's first task and "found a new file to process", but before starting the second task to load that file, the DAG schedule, automatically picked up and started to process the same file.

When the scheduled dag started, it paused executing the manually triggered DAG.
After the scheduled DAG finished, it went back to running the tasks from the manually triggered DAG which caused a failed state since the DAG moves files to an archive from a source directory, and the manually scheduled DAG started processing a file that "it believed was there" due to the success and information from the first task.

So:
DAG manually triggered
DAG manually Triggered Task 1 Executed
DAG scheduled invoked
DAG scheduled task 1 executed
DAG scheduled task 2 executed
DAG scheduled task 3 executed
DAG scheduled completed as Success
DAG manually Triggered Task 2 Failed (because of scheduled task 2 moving file detected in task 1)
DAG manually triggered skips other tasks due to failed task 2.
DAG manually triggered complete as Failed

So, my question is:
How do I configure Airflow such that invocations of the same DAG are executed FIFO, regardless if the DAG was invoked by a schedule, manual, or trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question:

> Why do Apache Airflow scheduled DAGs prioritize over manually
>   triggered DAGs?

I can not say something. But probably is a good idea take a look on airflow code.

Regarding the task you want to accomplish:

working with files in mounted folder (or similar), I can suggest you that the first thing to do is copy them in another folder lets say "process folder" in order to be sure that these files are untouchable by "others".

In my project we work with group of videos and we generate trigger related folder using the {{ ts_nodash }} default variable.